# Why would one use the Innodb Plugin instead of the builtin Innodb in Mysql 5.1? (GPL)

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.1

Innodb works in Mysql 5.1 whether or not the innodb plugin, ha_innodb_plugin.so is loaded at startup or not. Configuration dependent of course.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of either using or not using the builtin or modular innodb features?

Thanks very much for any explanation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The InnoDB plugin came into existence in MySQL 5.1 since version 5.1.38.

Many new features in the plugin allow you to

- make InnoDB access more CPUs

  - [innodb_read_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_read_io_threads)
  - [innodb_write_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads)
- scale up InnoDB to match the IOPs of your disk ([innodb_io_capacity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_io_capacity))

You are better off upgrading to MySQL 5.6 which has surpassed MySQL 5.1/5.5 because in  5.6

- you can dump the buffer pool to disk on shutdown and reload it on startup
- you can segment the buffer pool into buffer pool instances to help prevent swapping if the buffer pool is more than 50% of installed RAM

I would suggest you upgrade to MySQL 5.6 instead of dealing with enabling the old 5.1 plugin

Comment: +1 Another good feature of the InnoDB plugin is [fast index creation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-create-index.html).