# How to configure my.cnf for Mysql 5.1, which is using too much CPU?

Tags: mysql, performance, myisam, mysql-5.1, my.cnf

I am new Database engineer. I am having trouble in my server which is using too much CPU on database query(simple count statement). I have googled about it, so i found out it depends on system configuration. So I am posting the same. Here are the following stats of my server:

```
32 GB Ram
2.7 TB hard drive
150 GB database size(with 2 myisam tables contains billions of record)
mysql version 5.1
Centos
```

And here's my my.cnf file:

```
#datadir=/var/lib/mysql
datadir=/home/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
#socket=/home/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

There is not much details I think my.cnf is not configured according to system configuration.

Please let me know what is the best way I can set parameters in my.cnf so mysql works properly.

Output of Show variable;

```
SHOW VARIABLES;

| Variable_name                           | Value                                                                                     |
+-----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| auto_increment_increment                | 1     |
| auto_increment_offset                   | 1     |
| autocommit                              | ON    |
| automatic_sp_privileges                 | ON    |
| back_log                                | 50    |
| basedir                                 | /     |
| big_tables                              | OFF   |
| binlog_cache_size                       | 32768 |
| binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates | OFF   |
| binlog_format                           | STATEMENT |
| bulk_insert_buffer_size                 | 8388608   |
| character_sets_dir                      | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/|
| collation_connection                    | latin1_swedish_ci         |
| collation_database                      | latin1_swedish_ci         |
| collation_server                        | latin1_swedish_ci         |
| completion_type                         | 0                         |
| concurrent_insert                       | 1                         |
| connect_timeout                         | 10                        |
| datadir                                 | /home/mysql/              |
| default_week_format                     | 0                         |
| delay_key_write                         | ON                        |
| delayed_insert_limit                    | 100                       |
| delayed_insert_timeout                  | 300                       |
| delayed_queue_size                      | 1000                       |
| div_precision_increment                 | 4 |
| engine_condition_pushdown               | ON                                                                                        |
| error_count                             | 0         
| event_scheduler                         | OFF       
| expire_logs_days                        | 0         
| flush                                   | OFF       
| flush_time                              | 0         
| foreign_key_checks                      | ON          
| general_log                             | OFF         
| general_log_file                        | /home/mysql/localhost.log                                                                 |
| group_concat_max_len                    | 1024        
| identity                                | 0           
| ignore_builtin_innodb                   | OFF         
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index              | ON          
| innodb_additional_mem_pool_size         | 1048576     
| innodb_autoextend_increment             | 8           
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode                | 1           
| innodb_buffer_pool_size                 | 8388608
| innodb_checksums                        | ON     
| innodb_commit_concurrency               | 0      
| innodb_concurrency_tickets              | 500    
| innodb_data_file_path                   | ibdata1:10M:autoextend 
| innodb_doublewrite                      | ON     
| innodb_fast_shutdown                    | 1      
| innodb_file_io_threads                  | 4      
| innodb_file_per_table                   | OFF
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit          | 1  
| innodb_flush_method                     |    
| innodb_force_recovery                   | 0  
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout                | 50 
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog          | OFF
| innodb_log_buffer_size                  | 1048576                                                                                   |
| innodb_log_file_size                    | 5242880  
| innodb_log_files_in_group               | 2        
| innodb_log_group_home_dir               | ./       
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct              | 90       
| innodb_max_purge_lag                    | 0        
| innodb_mirrored_log_groups              | 1        
| innodb_open_files                       | 300      
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout              | OFF      
| innodb_stats_method                     | nulls_equal                                                                               |
| innodb_stats_on_metadata                | ON  
| innodb_support_xa                       | ON  
| innodb_sync_spin_loops                  | 20  
| innodb_table_locks                      | ON                                                                                        |
| innodb_thread_concurrency               | 8              
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay               | 10000          
| innodb_use_legacy_cardinality_algorithm | ON             
| insert_id                               | 0              
| interactive_timeout                     | 28800          
| join_buffer_size                        | 131072         
| keep_files_on_create                    | OFF            
| key_buffer_size                         | 8384512        
| key_cache_age_threshold                 | 300            
| key_cache_block_size                    | 1024           
| key_cache_division_limit                | 100            
| long_query_time                         | 10.000000                                                                                 |
| max_allowed_packet                      | 1048576                                                                                   |
| max_binlog_cache_size                   | 18446744073709547520                                                                      |
| max_binlog_size                         | 1073741824                                                                                |
| max_connect_errors                      | 10                                                                                        |
| max_connections                         | 151                                                                                       |
| max_delayed_threads                     | 20                                                                                        |
| max_error_count                         | 64                                                                                        |
| max_heap_table_size                     | 16777216                                                                                  |
| max_insert_delayed_threads              | 20                                                                                        |
| max_join_size                           | 18446744073709551615                                                                      |
| max_length_for_sort_data                | 1024                                                                                      |
| max_long_data_size                      | 1048576                                                                                   |
| max_prepared_stmt_count                 | 16382                                                                                     |
| max_relay_log_size                      | 0                                                                                         |
| max_seeks_for_key                       | 18446744073709551615                                                                      |
| max_sort_length                         | 1024                                                                                      |
| max_sp_recursion_depth                  | 0                                                                                         |
| max_tmp_tables                          | 32                                                                                        |
| max_user_connections                    | 0                                                                                         |
| max_write_lock_count                    | 18446744073709551615                                                                      |
| min_examined_row_limit                  | 0                                                                                         |
| multi_range_count                       | 256                                                                                       |
| myisam_data_pointer_size                | 6                                                                                         |
| myisam_max_sort_file_size               | 9223372036853727232                                                                       |
| myisam_mmap_size                        | 18446744073709551615                                                                      |
| myisam_recover_options                  | OFF                                                                                       |
| myisam_repair_threads                   | 1                                                                                         |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size                 | 8388608                                                                                   |
| myisam_stats_method                     | nulls_unequal                                                                             |
| myisam_use_mmap                         | OFF                                                                                       |
| net_buffer_length                       | 16384                                                                                     |
| net_read_timeout                        | 30                                                                                        |
| net_retry_count                         | 10                                                                                        |
| net_write_timeout                       | 60                                                                                        |
| open_files_limit                        | 1024                                                                                      |
| optimizer_prune_level                   | 1                                                                                         |
| optimizer_search_depth                  | 62                                                                                        |
| optimizer_switch                        | index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on |
| pid_file                                | /home/mysql/localhost.localdomain.pid                                                     |
| plugin_dir                              | /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin                                                                   |
| port                                    | 3306                                                                                      |
| preload_buffer_size                     | 32768                                                                                     |
| profiling                               | OFF                                                                                       |
| profiling_history_size                  | 15                                                                                        |
| protocol_version                        | 10                                                                                        |
| pseudo_thread_id                        | 18                                                                                        |
| query_alloc_block_size                  | 8192                                                                                      |
| query_cache_limit                       | 1048576                                                                                   |
| query_cache_min_res_unit                | 4096                                                                                      |
| query_cache_size                        | 0                                                                                         |
| query_cache_type                        | ON                                                                                        |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate            | OFF                                                                                       |
| query_prealloc_size                     | 8192                                                                                      |
| range_alloc_block_size                  | 4096                                                                                      |
| read_buffer_size                        | 131072                                                                                    |
| read_only                               | OFF                                                                                       |
| read_rnd_buffer_size                    | 262144                                                                                    |
| rpl_recovery_rank                       | 0                                                                                         |
| secure_auth                             | OFF                                                                                       |       |skip_external_locking                   | ON                                                                                        |
| slow_launch_time                        | 2                                                                                         |
| slow_query_log                          | OFF                                                                                       |
| slow_query_log_file                     | /home/mysql/localhost-slow.log                                                            |
| socket                                  | /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock                                                                 |
| sort_buffer_size                        | 2097144                                                                                   |
| sql_auto_is_null                        | ON                                                                                        |
| sql_big_selects                         | ON                                                                                        |
| sql_big_tables                          | OFF                                                                                       |
| sql_buffer_result                       | OFF                                                                                       |
| sql_log_bin                             | ON                                                                                        |
| sql_log_off                             | OFF                                                                                       |
| sql_log_update                          | ON                                                                                        |
| sql_low_priority_updates                | OFF                                                                                       |
| sql_max_join_size                       | 18446744073709551615                                                                      |
| sql_mode                                |                                                                                           |
| sql_notes                               | ON                                                                                        |
| sql_quote_show_create                   | ON                                                                                        |
| sql_safe_updates                        | OFF                                                                                       |
| sql_select_limit                        | 18446744073709551615                                                                      |
| sql_slave_skip_counter                  |                                                                                           |
| sql_warnings                            |                                                                                          |
| storage_engine                          | MyISAM                                                                                    |
| table_definition_cache                  | 256                                                                                       |
| table_lock_wait_timeout                 | 50                                                                                        |
| table_open_cache                        | 64                                                                                        |
| table_type                              | MyISAM                                                                                    |
| thread_cache_size                       | 0                                                                                         |
| thread_handling                         | one-thread-per-connection                                                                 |
| thread_stack                            | 262144                                                                                    |
                                                                              |
| timestamp                               | 1401967364                                                                                |
| tmp_table_size                          | 16777216                                                                                  |
| tmpdir                                  | /tmp                                                                                      |
| transaction_alloc_block_size            | 8192                                                                                      |
| transaction_prealloc_size               | 4096                                                                                      |
| tx_isolation                            | REPEATABLE-READ
```

### | version                                 | 5.1.66-community

Comment: Just a suggestion, but if you *_could_* upgrade to 5.6 (and since you're using the community edition - why not?), you could then take advantage of the performance schema enhancements which are the MySQL team's efforts to remove the "vary-the-parameters-until-it-works" approach to tuning and instead put efforts like yours onto a firmer "scientific" footing. If you can find out where the system is spending its time, then you can tackle the problem.

Comment: Have you tried mysqltuner.pl? Good thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282232/mysql-high-cpu-usage)

Comment: I cannot install such plugins on production. All i can do right now is changes in my.cnf

Comment: And your test system?

Comment: i dont have 32gb ram, so i cant test with my.cnf parameters.

Comment: OK - well run mysqltuner with your test system and see if there's any/much overhead (I don't think there will be). Then, perhaps at a quiet time, run it (in production) and see what it gives you?

Comment: You can refer Percona's Configuration Wizard to configure your MySQL server settings I hope this helps https://tools.percona.com/wizard

Comment: @Aarmir "I am having trouble in my server which is using too much CPU on database query(simple count statement)." If you post 1) the query, 2) the EXPLAIN output for the query, 3) SHOW TABLE definitions, and 4) some information about the CPUs in the server, someone can probably advise you on whether it's possible to reduce CPU usage from the query.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved ? Did you upgrade to MySQL 5.6 ?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I have solved this issue by using summary tables. But there is one more issue I am engaged and I really appreciate your help on it. Please have a look into this thread -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297801/how-to-configure-my-cnf-in-5-6-17/26297892#26297892

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for that large data, you should consider upgrading MySQL 5.6 and converting your tables to InnoDB, because even though MyISAM is faster on especially reading, this feature is lost as your database grows. And your database is way more more larger than that limit.
MyISAM tables use table-level locking. Based on your traffic estimates, you have close to 200 writes per second. With MyISAM, only one of these could be in progress at any time. You have to make sure that your hardware can keep up with these transaction to avoid being overrun, i.e., a single query can take no more than 5ms.

And as my.cnf, this could be a start point for your system to check performance.

> [mysqld]
>   open-files-limit=65535
>   expire-logs-days=14
>   max-allowed-packet=64M
>   max-connect-errors=10000
>   tmp-table-size=512M
>   max-heap-table-size=256M
>   query-cache-type=0
>   query-cache-size=0
>   max-connections=1000
>   thread-cache-size=100
>   open-files-limit=655350
>   table-definition-cache=1024
>   table-open-cache=2048
>   innodb-lock-wait-timeout=240
>   slow-query-log=0
>   long-query-time=10
>   log-error=/var/log/mysql-error.log
>   innodb-purge-batch-size=10000
>   innodb-rollback-on-timeout
>   [mysqldump]
>   quick
>   single-transaction
>   max_allowed_packet             = 16M
>   [mysql]
>   no_auto_rehash
>   [myisamchk]
>   key_buffer                     = 512M
>   sort_buffer_size               = 512M
>   read_buffer                    = 64M
>   write_buffer                   = 64M
>   [mysqld_safe]
>   open-files-limit               = 32768
>   myisam_recover                 = backup,force

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I did not answer this one right away. Here it goes:

Since the MySQL version was MySQL 5.1.66, there was something that could have been done to increase CPU performance the right way. Historically speaking, MySQL 5.1.38 was the first version of MySQL 5 to introduce [innodb_read_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_read_io_threads) and [innodb_write_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads) as configurable options.

I wrote about this many times

- `Sep 26, 2013` : [Why would one use the Innodb Plugin instead of the builtin Innodb in Mysql 5.1? (GPL)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50601/why-would-one-use-the-innodb-plugin-instead-of-the-builtin-innodb-in-mysql-5-1/50606#50606)
- `Jun 01, 2012` : [I've got 16GB of ram, how should I configure MySQL Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18670/ive-got-16gb-of-ram-how-should-i-configure-mysql-server/18675#18675)
- `May 17, 2012` : [MySQL - Master/Slave Replication with different server specs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18111/mysql-master-slave-replication-with-different-server-specs/18113#18113)

The main idea would be to have installed [InnoDB Plugin 1.0](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/). to start using those options. After installing the [InnoDB Plugin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/), I would have referred you to these posts on tuning:

- `Mar 16, 2012` : [Using multiple cores for single MySQL queries on Debian](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15146/using-multiple-cores-for-single-mysql-queries-on-debian/15185#15185)
- `Sep 20, 2011` : [Multi cores and MySQL Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5926/multi-cores-and-mysql-performance/5968#5968)
- `Sep 12, 2011` : [Possible to make MySQL use more than one core?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-than-one-core/5670#5670)
- `May 26, 2011` : [About single threaded versus multithreaded databases performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/about-single-threaded-versus-multithreaded-databases-performance/2948#2948)

Leaving the time warp, I would say simply upgrade to MySQL 5.6 and use my tuning suggestions. I would also convert all MyISAM to InnoDB.